# Как смержить ветку в другой проект?

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть два проекта, модули для работы с бд у них идентичные и поэтому хочу слить их в один проект. Как можно смержить ветку с одного проекта с веткой из другого в gitlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя просто так взять и с одного проекта в другой влить кусок кода. Нужно, что бы у них было что то общее. К примеру, один является форком другого. Тогда pull request и готово.

Но как всегда есть много вариантов решить проблему.

1. Самый простой и наивный - просто скопипасть нужные файлы в другой проект и закоммитить. Готово. Для однократного переноса - ок, но для каждодневного - нет.
2. Более сложный способ - подготовить diff нужных файлов и перенести diff. в принципе, ничем не отличается от предыдущего по результату. Но есть дифф, поможно понять, что именно переноситься. Если изменений немного, то может это и более оптимальный способ.
3. Более красивый, но сложный. Модуль работы с базой выделить в отдельный репозиторий и подключить к обоим проектам как [сабмодуль](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).  Это достаточно гибкий метод - сабмодуль можно будет отдельно развивать, тестить. Но если пойдете этим путем, не делайте сабмодуль с сохранением дерева. Перенесите в другую папку. Иначе при любых действиях, которые затрагивают коммиты из "досабмодульного состояния", постоянно будут вылезать разные "проблемы с репой".